# Different use cases for default argument values

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can someone please explain the difference between:

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    L.append(a)
    return L

print f(1)
print f(2)
print f(3)
```

and

```
def f(a, L=None):
    if L is None:
        L = []
    L.append(a)
    return L

print f(1)
print f(2)
print f(3)
```

It's quite confusing for me. Thanks

Comment: Answer's link carries your same example - http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

Comment: thank you. it was very helpful